# VueJS zooms all five images at once

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to zoom images one by one. But this code right now works like this: I click on image and zooms all five images at once and then after another click they all zoom out. How to fix this so I can zoom them one by one ?

```
       <img src="/images/{{advertisement.img}}" class="mr-3" :style="{ width: imageWidth + 'px', height: imageHeight + 'px' }"
        @click="toggleZoom">

        <img src="/images/{{advertisement.img2}}" class="mr-3" :style="{ width: imageWidth + 'px', height: imageHeight + 'px' }"
        @click="toggleZoom">

        <img src="/images/{{advertisement.img3}}" class="mr-3" :style="{ width: imageWidth + 'px', height: imageHeight + 'px' }"
        @click="toggleZoom">

        <img src="/images/{{advertisement.img4}}" class="mr-3" :style="{ width: imageWidth + 'px', height: imageHeight + 'px' }"
        @click="toggleZoom">

        <img src="/images/{{advertisement.img5}}" class="mr-3" :style="{ width: imageWidth + 'px', height: imageHeight + 'px' }"
        @click="toggleZoom">
```

VueJS part.

```
   new Vue({
        el: '#advertisementManagement', 
        data: {
            isZoomed: false,
            imageWidth: '',
            imageHeight: ''
        },
        methods: {
            zoomIn() {
                this.isZoomed = true;
                this.imageWidth = 300;
                this.imageHeight = 300;              
            },
            zoomOut() {
                this.isZoomed = false;
                this.imageWidth = 100;
                this.imageHeight = 100;                 
            }
        },
        computed: {
        toggleZoom() {
            return this.isZoomed ? this.zoomOut : this.zoomIn;
            }         
        }        
    });
```

Comment: Is `advertisement` part of your `data`?

Comment: You are using your component's `imageWidth` and `imageHeight` for each image. Then on clicking one, you set the components `imageWidth` and `imageHeight` - they all resize. It is doing exactly what you ask.

Comment: @Terry Yes. I get images from DB,

Comment: @RandyCasburn So for each image I need to create new method ?

Comment: At a minimum, you need to effect each image individually. Meaning: each image's height and width must be changed individually. Most likely easiest approach would be to use the event target.

Comment: The best approach is to create an atomic component that handles the images individually: in that case, the component will be able to track the zoomed state and dimensions of the image individually :) the app should not need to know the dimensions nor the state of the ad images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to abstract them into individual components, or at least declare a zoomed state for each individual image. That is because the `this.isZoomed` state is stored on the app level where *all* the images reside in, which means each image does not store its individual zoomed state.

VueJS makes atomic design extremely easy: in this case, your advertisement image is the atomic component since it should handle its own state. This can be done by creating a custom component, say `<ad-image>`, that will track the individual `isZoomed` state of the image, as well as its dimensions:

```js
Vue.component('ad-image', {
  template: '#ad-image',
  props: {
    src: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      width: 300,
      height: 300,
      isZoomed: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    zoomIn() {
      this.isZoomed = true;
      this.width = 300;
      this.height = 300;
    },
    zoomOut() {
      this.isZoomed = false;
      this.width = 100;
      this.height = 100;
    }
  },
  computed: {
    toggleZoom() {
      return this.isZoomed ? this.zoomOut : this.zoomIn;
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#advertisementManagement',
  data: {
    advertisement: {
      img: 'https://via.placeholder.com/300x300',
      img2: 'https://via.placeholder.com/300x300',
      img3: 'https://via.placeholder.com/300x300',
      img4: 'https://via.placeholder.com/300x300'
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="advertisementManagement">
  <ad-image :src="advertisement.img" />
  <ad-image :src="advertisement.img2" />
  <ad-image :src="advertisement.img3" />
  <ad-image :src="advertisement.img4" />
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="ad-image">
  <img :src="src" class="mr-3" :style="{ width: width + 'px', height: height + 'px' }" @click="toggleZoom" />
</script>
```

Pro-tip: you can abstract all style bindings into a computed property, so that you don't clutter your VueJS template with string interpolations and concatenations:

```
<img :src="src" class="mr-3" :style="styleObject" @click="toggleZoom" />
```

And then in your JS logic:

```
computed: {
  toggleZoom() {
    return this.isZoomed ? this.zoomOut : this.zoomIn;
  },
  styleObject() {
    return {
        width: width + 'px',
        height: height + 'px'
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: But why this shows only first `img` and not all five ?